# How to initialize flowplayer for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I have an array of videos, and I want to initialize the player for each div that contains video.

In my JS code I build divs like:

```
<div id="player+{{$index}}"></div>    // "player" + index is calculate dynamically by js function
```

Then:

```
 dscPlayer.initialize(urlvideo,coverUrl,id);

initialize : function(urlvideo,coverUrl,id) {

            flowplayer("player"+id, 
            {....
```

But I don't see the video. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems you'd like to assign a unique ID to each `div` element. The syntax you're using however would require the engine to read your mind; unless I'm missing something. I suggest you rephrase the question as "How can I assign a unique ID to multiple HTML elements programmatically?" or something similar. Note that depending on your scenario, you might not even need unique IDs.

Comment: In the browser console I see the unique id in this way: palyer1,player2..

Comment: Oh, so you mean the HTML snippet is pseudocode? My bad then.

Comment: Yes....in my js function I append dynamically the div in the container

Comment: do you append the div before you initialise the flowplayer?

Comment: Removed the redundant tag-in-title, used real HTML instead of the pseudocode that confused some commenters, removed "thanks", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at the [documentation](https://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html), it seems you're attempting to use the "manual installation" method (i.e. you're not using the `flowplayer` *HTML class*).

However, the global `flowplayer` *function* doesn't seem to be used for setup, instead it is used for [programmatic access to the player's behavior](https://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html).

What is described in the manual setup documentation is the use of the `flowplayer` jQuery *plugin* (not the global function).

```
$('player' + id).flowplayer({ ...
```

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with `flowplayer` at all, just trying to help interpret the documentation (which I've only glanced at), I could have easily missed something.